# To store the image with date time stamp on sdcard

Tags: android, image, datetime, android-sdcard

I have Written the code to store the bitmap Image in sdcard But I want to store it along with the date time stamp .How to do it ?

```
bmp = processFrame(mCamera);
                String i1=bmp.toString();
                String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
                    myDir.mkdirs();
                    Random generator = new Random();
                    int n = 10000;
                    n = generator.nextInt(n);
                    String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                    File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                    if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
                    try {
                           FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                           out.flush();
                           out.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
String fname = "Image-"+ n +System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg";
```

instead of

```
String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
```

try this :

```
String getCurrentDate() {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String Month = "";
        switch (c.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {
        case 0:
              Month = "Jan";
              break;
        case 1:
              Month = "Feb";
              break;
        case 2:
              Month = "Mar";
              break;
        case 3:
              Month = "Apr";
              break;
        case 4:
              Month = "May";
              break;
        case 5:
              Month = "June";
              break;
        case 6:
              Month = "July";
              break;
        case 7:
              Month = "Aug";
              break;
        case 8:
              Month = "Sep";
              break;
        case 9:
              Month = "Oct";
              break;
        case 10:
              Month = "Nov";
              break;
        case 11:
              Month = "Dec";
              break;
        default:
              break;
        }
        int ampm = c.get(Calendar.AM_PM);
        String amorpm = "";
        if (ampm == 1) {
              amorpm = "PM";
        } else {
              amorpm = "AM";
        }
        String date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + Month + "/"
                    + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":"
                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " + amorpm;
        // int Day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        // int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        return date;
  }
```

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()); with this code I am getting date time But how to store it to image

Comment: instead of String fname = "Image-"+ n +System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg"; use  String fname = "Image-"+ n +getCurrentDate() +".jpg";

Comment: When I am doing that changes Image not getting stored

Comment: are you getting any warning in the logcat?

Comment: Well i think i got the issue. File names should not have a <> or / or * and so on check the name of the file that you are getting

Comment: I am nor getting what you want to say

Comment: check heading Forbidden characters in filenames in http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html

Comment: Then can we write it on image

Comment: 2012-09-10 13:56:54 I am getting date time like this

Comment: yes you can. try using this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002722/draw-text-on-top-of-bitmap-failed

Comment: You cant use a : in file names. That's the issue

Comment: can we parse it to 2012-09-10 13 -56-54 how to do it

Comment: what do you want to parse it to?

Comment: hey use the code that i posted if you want the format you want.

Comment: Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        String date = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + "/"
                + c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + " " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR) + "-"
                + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " " ; 

  System.out.println(" "+date);

Comment: Can i get this time stamp on Images

Comment: Is this what you need? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125898/display-time-and-date-on-capture-image/13126150#13126150